# Pass string literal as char* via argument

Tags: c++, string, arguments

I made a function which change string, see the following code.

```
void Test(char* str, char c) {
    str[1] = c;
}

int main(){
    Test("Hi", '2');
}
```

I notice it made some run time error. I know how to prevent the error.

```
char buff[3] = "Hi";
Test(buff,'2');
```

but I don't know why the first example made run time error. I guess, if I pass string directly, it becomes const char. Does anyone explain what happened exactly?

ps.
what if I use char* str = "hi", then pass it into the argument?

```
char* buff = "Hi";
Test(buff,'2');
```

like this. Can I modify buff?

Comment: Read something about `const char*`.

Comment: This isn't legal C++ any more (as in shouldn't compile) and has never been right.

Comment: The last one being new, I presume it's supposed to be `char *buff`, but still no. Using a pointer to non-constant data to point to constant data will never work regardless of how you try to get around it.

Comment: See my edit about `char* str = "hi"`.

Comment: sorry, chris. i'd like to write char* buff.

Answer (score 3):

Because `"Hi"` is *string literal* and it's not allowed to be modified, they are read-only (the type of string literal is `const char[n]`).

Modifying it is *undefined behavior*.

---

Regarding your edit: `char* str = "hi"` is invalid, it should be `const char* str = "hi"`. Which is pointer to `const char`. Again, modifying it is disallowed.

Comment: True if he had declared `char* buff = "Hi"` (which would place `buff` in the read-only code section instead of in the stack).

Comment: @barak OP *did* (implicitly) declare it like that. This answer is correct.

Comment: Note: `const char[N]`, though.

Comment: @barakmanos; you need to double check the question, it's the first case which is giving him problems

Comment: @Kiril Kirov: Try for yourself: When `char buff[3] = "Hi"`, `buff` is placed in the stack of the calling function, or in the data-section of the program (if declared globally). Both the stack and the data-section are Read-Write sections. When 'const char buff[3] = "Hi"` or `char* buff = "Hi"`, `buff is placed in the code-section of the program, which is a Read-Only section.

Comment: @barakmanos, No, `buff` is still placed on the stack. The string literal has static storage duration and is, itself, non-modifiable without consequences, like any other constant data. The only thing you're doing different is copying the string as opposed to pointing to it.

Comment: @chris: correct, but that literal is copied into the `buff` array

Comment: @barakmanos - OP says, that the second case with the `buff` array works. And nobody says the opposite. The question (and my answer) are for the first case, where there's no `buff` array. Read the question again, please.

Comment: My apology to all the above users, I stand corrected; the `char buff[3]` is what he used in order to solve this problem. The answer (as suggested here) is that `"Hi"` is located in the code-section (which is RO), whereas with `char buff[3] = "Hi"`, `buff` is located in the stack (which is RW).

Comment: @barakmanos - correct. Thanks for the understanding. Can you revert your down-vote now?

Comment: Thanks folks! you guys give me new idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't explicitly allocate memory for strings, compiler stores them in read-only memory. So, any modification to such strings result in run time error.

```
Test("Hi", '2');
```

Here in the above case "Hi" string is stored in read-only memory.

```
 char *buff = "Hi";  
 Test(buff,'2');
```

Here also "Hi" is stored in the read-only memory and the starting address is returned to *buff* character pointer, which is same as above. You can overcome such errors by allocating memory for the string and then pass that reference. Like

```
 char buff[3] = "Hi";  
 Test(buff,'2');
```

or

```
char *buff = (char *)malloc(SIZE);  
strcpy(buff, "Hi");
Test(buff,'2');
```

Please refer to this link http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/

Answer (score 0):

Often string constants are in read-only memory, causing a runtime error when you attempt to modify it.

In your second example, you put the string into a buffer on the stack, so it can be updated without error.

Answer (score 0):

Literal strings are not modifiable. When I compile your code with GCC I get the warning:

```
testptr.cpp:6: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Runtime Error:**

```
char* buff = "Hi"; // buff points to an address in the code-section, which is a Read-Only section
buff[1] = 'x';     // Illegal memory access violation
```

**Compilation Error:**

```
const char* buff = "Hi"; // This is a correct declaration, which will prevent the runtime error above
buff[1] = 'x';           // The compiler will not allow this
```

**All Good:**

```
char buff[] = "Hi"; // buff points to an address in the stack or the data-section, which are both Read-Write sections
buff[1] = 'x';      // Works OK
```

**Notes:**

1. In all cases, a string "Hi" is placed in the code-section of the program.
2. In the last example, the contents of that string are copied into the `buff` array.
3. In the last example, the `buff` array is located in the stack if `buff` is a non-static local variable, and in the data-section of the program otherwise.